# Why h4 is the best move here?

Tags: analysis

[image]

Is not bishop to e2 better? Why does the kingside has to be weakened like this?

Thanks everyone for your answers. You all argue that the knight must remain on f4 so h4 prevents kicking it out. However, I just found another game in which h4 is played and this time there is no keeping the knight on f4. Could someone tell me what else happens here?

[image]

Comment: Can I vote +3 to this question?

Comment: @thb Of course you can

Comment: @Timetraveler please, give a link to the game, otherwise it's very time consuming to find the game for analysis.

Comment: Sorry for that. The link of the last game is: https://lichess.org/caIfDMgT/white#10

Comment: @Timetraveler please, see below for the second part of the answer

Comment: Please don't add on to the question with a totally new question.  The second diagram is a totally different position.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're trying to analyze the very equal position with no significant tactical potential. Depending on minor tweaks of your engine settings, you may get a few "good" moves, including `Be2`, `Ba3`, `c5` -- all approximately equal.

Computers at lichess have limited resources, hence they spot only obvious stuff, and have a limited precision when evaluating moves.

If you move `h4` -- you're down about 0.1 pawn, I would not lose a sleep about that, `Be2` is good enough and you should not worry what stupid engine says =)

**Disclosure**: I'm actually running one of the lichess analysis boxes, so I took a deep dive into the details. Here's what I found:

1. From your screen shot, you're running analysis on your local iPad, which is slow and may take some time to arrive to the good result. It would be much preferable to run the server side analysis, much faster and more precise.
2. I have found the game in question among your games and analysed it using various engines available. Most of the engines recommend `c5` as the best continuation for White. However, for the lichess analysis we use a very conservative settings of Stockfish ("Analysis Contempt" is turned Off), this changes the focus from the active attacking moves to the "safe" defensive ones. And `h4` is one of those nice safe moves.

As I have said earlier, it all depends on the minor tweaks of the engine parameters, the score difference is negligible and `h4` is no better and no worse than a few other moves -- play what you like and don't worry about what computer says.

---

Answering the second part of your question, here's my analysis:

[image]

`Bd3` seems to be "the best", with `h4` and `Be3` sharing the second place. Actually, while analysis was running, 4 or 5 top pretenders constantly swapped their places, sometimes `h4` was on the top. Probably, if I run the analysis deeper, there will be a few moments when any of the top 5 moves will be declared "the best".

All in all, the analysis is not exhaustive, and it does not guarantee to give you the "absolute best move". The main purpose of the analysis was to spot your mistakes (8. h3? was clearly a mistake, losing 0.5 pawn), and propose something better, not necessarily the best.

Here's the analysis @ depth 24, `h4` is way below.

[image]

Comment: Engines also assume opponents make the GTO play (at least, as best as they can calculate) - but it doesn't take long to play with an engine to realize the difference between a human move and an engine move. You see it a lot when playing long clock games and people have lots of time to go coddle their engine.

Comment: @corsiKa what's GTO ?

Comment: Was the engine intentionally tuned to be defensive or why was this configuration made? I would have expected the engine to be tuned for maximum strength.

Comment: @usr the engine tuned to the "maximum strength" is a very broad definition. There are ways to play against ELO1500 players, which differ from 2000+, which, in turn, differ from the settings used for computer-to-computer matches. The current setting is a bit conservative, but this might prevent an unusually high scores for very active, tactical positions where a bit of risk usually pays off. IANAL (I am not a lawyer), it's my personal opinion, which might differ from the "official" point of view =)

Comment: @lenik. Thanks for answering. But I still cannot see why h4 is any better than h3. With h3, I wanted to prevent the knight from going to g4

Comment: @Timetraveler `h4` prevents `g5` and threatens `h5` with the further attack on the king, `h3` prevents.... well... imho, nothing, just wastes a perfectly good move =)

Comment: @lenik GTO is Game Theory Optimal - meaning you've achieved a perfect Nash equilibrium with the given set of moves.

Comment: @Timetraveler and while we're at it, please, take a look at your score graph in the second game. It looks pretty much as WWW -- you and your partner are deliberately trying to lose about 0.5 pawn every move, this is not very good pattern. Remember, you cannot WIN the game, you can only let your partner to LOSE, make a few solid moves and your partner will hang himself without your help =)

Comment: @lenik I do not mistakes on purpose =). I always fail to see these kind of moves amd miscalculate some tactic motif. I also make a lot of mistakes in the midgame but I can’t help it.

Comment: @Timetraveler I do the same mistakes, don't worry, everybody does that. I'd recommend to do a little paradigm shift -- don't try to "win" the game, you can't and nobody can do that. Just wait for the opponent to make a mistake and take and advantage of it. The "puzzle" section helps a lot with tactical vision, once you learn to recognise the common mistake patterns, you'll be winning in no time =)

Comment: @lenik By the way, aboutnthe first diagram, what happens if black eventually manages to place one of their knights on e6 or g6? I mean you will have to exchange the knight in order to avoid doubled pawns and the weaking advance of the pawn to h4 will have been for nothing(if we do not count the fact that it prevented g5).

Comment: @Timetraveler probably, there are other people around with much higher ratings than me, but I would not worry about those knighs, because 1) it takes a few moves to get them there 2) after `g3` I'd be happy to have double pawns on the F vertical, if that means the white Bishop will have virtually zero chance to participate in the game and half-open G vertical that will lead straight to the black king.

Comment: @lenik Sorry but my problem with h4 still persists. In the 8th move, I should have played h4 but no clue why. I think that it is a rush attack against the kinside, other moves like Bd3 or Nf3 should be better I figured. The game is https://lichess.org/cW7O84oD/white#14

Comment: @Timetraveler probably this is somehow related with e6-f6-g6 pawn structure, preventing `g5`, but I agree with you it does not look reasonable to me and definitely I'd develop other pieces before even thinking about `h4`.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned, it's all about keeping the Knight on f4.  That outpost needs to be maintained and ...g5 is stopped by h4! Yes, g4 is weakened but to quote Bobby: "You have to give up squares to get squares".

Also note that if Black plays ...h6 hoping to play ...g5 you can play h5 and that knight is not going anywhere.

Piece activity can be more important that weak squares or even weakened structures.  You can go over the Kasparov - Short world championship match an see how Short took on doubled pawns, etc. but was compensated by good pieces.

Comment: But why is that important to maintain the Knight on f4? Let's say `10. Be2 g5, 11.Nd5` it looks perfectly fine for White.

Comment: @Ywapom. But still, with h4 you are not ensuring that the knight will remain on f4. I mean later on, one knight can move to e6 or g6 to exchange your knight on f4.

Comment: @Akavall Whites Nf4 is his best active piece, he doesn't want it made to leave so easily.  Black will have to make a lot of maneuvers to try and get rid of it, which allows White time to improve his position.

Answer (score 4):

With h4 you prevent g5, which would kick your knight.

Comment: h4 seriously weakens g4 though.

Answer (score 1):

As a novice, it's hard for me to see why 1. Be2 g5 2. Nd5 is putting White at a major disadvantage, but I do feel it puts White on the defensive. Black has gained space and potentially a kingside attack, but may be overextending. White's knight is centralized, and black may trade it away leading to a centralized pawn structure for White with a potential target pawn aiding the Black's light bishop and weakening White's. White needs to protect their center while anticipating heavy kingside pressure in terms of pawn pushing backed by rooks.

Compare that to 1. g5, where White seems to be restricting Black's expansion. This may allow White to develop into a stronger attack without worrying about the kingside pressure.

I'm unsure about responding to g5 by moving the knight to the h-file. I don't see any benefits to White's position there.

Comment: One thing you're not mentioning is that white currently has space and so should try avoiding pieces. After Be2 g5, Nd5 Be6, white is forced to trade the central knight.

Answer (score 0):

I am writing this answer in order to explain my thoughts about the second position I provided.
 I have come to the conclusion after playing similar positions that h4 is played in order to weaken my rival’s kingside. That is why they have to play right away h5. Otherwise, my h pawn will have to be exchanged by the g pawn, opening a file for my rook. 
Although admittedly this does weaken my own kingside, there seems to be no danger and probably, I will eventually castle queenside.
The sinequan reason for playing h4 though is that my rival has played g6 in order to fianchetto his bishop and so a weakening can be induced in my opponent pawn structure.
In case someone has concluded something different feel free to correct me.